# onCompleteListener vs onSuccessListener en Firestore, ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Para buscar un campo de un documento en específico en [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) tengo dos formas que me funcionan igual.

#### Con `OnSuccessListener`:

```
   DocumentReference docRef = 
    db.collection("extras").document("midoc").collection("micol").document("1");

    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            String text=documentSnapshot.getString("texto");
            mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(text));
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

---

#### Con `OnCompleteListener`:

```
   DocumentReference docRef = 
    db.collection("extras").document("midoc").collection("micol").document("1");

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    txtOutput=document.getString("texto");
                } else {
                    txtOutput="Documento no encontrado";
                }
            } else {
                txtOutput=task.getException().getMessage();
            }
            mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(txtOutput));
        }
        
    });
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos formas? ¿Se recomienda una en concreto para este caso (es cuestión de encontrar el valor del campo `texto` en el documento `1`)?

Answer (score 2):

Una tarea es exitosa cuando el trabajo representado por la tarea finaliza, como se esperaba, sin errores.

Ten en cuenta también que si hay una pérdida de conectividad de red (no hay conexión de red en tu dispositivo), no se activa `onSuccessListener()`, lo mismo pasa con `onFailureListener()`.

Este comportamiento tiene sentido, ya que la tarea solo se considera completada cuando los datos se han confirmado (o rechazado) en los servidores `Firebase`.

En tu caso ambos casos hacen lo mismo debido a esta particularidad, uno de ellos, siempre será llamado sin importar si fue exitosa o no (`OnCompleteListener`), ya que la tarea fue completada, y para el otro caso también se ejecutara debido a que se completo de manera exitosa sin contratiempo alguno (`OnSuccessListener`).

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la descripción te darás una idea de la principal diferencia:

> **[OnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnCompleteListener)**: llamado cuando una tarea se completa.
>
> **[OnSuccessListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener)**: llamado cuando una tarea se completa con éxito.

---

[OnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnCompleteListener) se llama cuando la tarea finaliza, pero no importando si realizo el proceso exitosa mente o fallo. En el caso de tu programa no fallo por esa razón aparentemente tienen el mismo funcionamiento.

En cambio [OnSuccessListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener) determinas que no hubo ninguna falla al realizar la tarea,  generalmente yo lo uso junto con [OnFailureListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnFailureListener) para determinar otra acción en caso de falla.

```
  docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    });


  docRef.get().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    });
```